# Remove from Google Tags with less than 2 posts

Tags: plugins, tags

I would like to write some code that remove from google the tag pages which contains only a few posts.

I can do it by modifying the meta tag and the HTTP response header to 410. But how can I implement that in Wordpress?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-response-code.php to set the response header, and you just need to find the lines in the theme's header.php. Unfortunately, these items *are* set by header.php so you will have to run the code on all pages of a traditional theme, but I would do something in the header.php near where the meta is currently being set like

```
if ( is_tag() ){
// check for how many posts are in the loop here and save as number
}
if (is_tag() && $number < 3){
//change meta here, change http response code here
}
else{
// normal meta here, normal response code here
}
```

Comment: But how do I check how many posts are in that tag?